# Вопрос по разработке мессенджера на сокетах

Tags: java, сокет, socket.io, сокеты

Возникла идея написать небольшой мессенджер на Java. За основу сокеты. В данный момент, есть следующая архитектура:
Клиент выполняет какие-то действия, в результате чего формируется JSON объект, который высылается на сервер, далее, сервер обрабатывает JSON-запрос и отправляет JSON-ответ, который обрабатывается на клиенте. 
Соответственно, все это работает на TCP протоколе. Клиент подключился, отправил запрос, принял ответ и отключился. 
Теперь основной вопрос. Есть 2 идеи, как обрабатывать входящие сообщение. Первая идея заключается в том, чтобы клиент в отдельном потоке, каждую, к примеру, секунду, отправлял серверу пакет с запросом обновления, а сервер в свою очередь отправлял обновления. Следующая идея заключается в хранении данных о клиентах на сервере, и в отдельном потоке установки соединения при пересылке сообщения. Не знаю, как это описать понятнее, надеюсь, это хоть как-то можно осознать. Как вы считаете, являются ли оба эти подхода не правильными, либо, возможно, их можно как-нибудь доработать. Так же буду очень благодарен за ваши идеи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие вещи делать проще на `WebSoket`-ах.

Но если Вы уже решили сделать на обычных сокетах то я вижу так:

При старте приложения запускается два потока, один служит для приёма сообщений от сервера, второй для передачи сообщения серверу (сообщения имеется в виду JSON строка). Программа не делает запрос каждую секунду, это затратно по ресурсам клиента и сервера. Когда кто-то кому-то написал, сервер отправляет сообщение клиенту (на сервере хранится инфа о всех подключенных клиентах в листе). Клиент принимает его и если чат с этим пользователем открыт то уже клиент добавляет сообщение, если же не открыт то отображает что есть непрочитанное сообщение.

Когда клиент запускает программу, автоматом шлется сообщение серверу о "дай мне кол-во непрочитанных по чатам". Сервер отдаёт эти данных. Но для этого нужно база.

Есть еще нюанс. Собеседник может быть не подключен. Поэтому нужно подумать как быть: Или запрещать писать пока собеседник не онлайн или же писать в бд, ну и потом из бд читать. Такое нужно еще в случае который описал Выше.

Comment: Да, это я и хотел объяснить под вторым пунктом. Ну, плюс-минус.